# Image not loaded in android version but works in ios version

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following code both for index.android.js and index.ios.js, but the image is not shown in android device, but shows in XCode simulator:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
} = React;

var Testing123 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.pic} source={{uri: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/6133685?v=3&s=460'}}>
            </Image>
        </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    pic: {
        width:100,
        height:100,
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Testing', () => Testing123);
```

Anyone has a clue why this is not working?

p.s.: Would it be related to this info from React Native's doc?

Memory issues with PNG images 
React Native Android depends on Fresco for loading and displaying images. Currently we have disabled downsampling because it is experimental, so you may run into memory issues when loading large PNG images.

Comment: I would try with other urls, see if it works. And I would try playing a little with the picture style (add background color to verify it's there, try absolute position...etc)

Comment: I tried with other images, some of them work in android, but some don't